# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when logging out

Tags: angular

I have a few links like this in my `app.component.html`:

```
<a *ngIf="!global.isLoggedIn()" routerLink="/account" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
<a *ngIf="global.isLoggedIn()" routerLink="/account-logout" routerLinkActive="active">Logout</a>
```

in `app.component.ts` I have this:

```
constructor(private global: GlobalService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
```

in my `global.service.ts` I have:

```
public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn();
}
```

in my `authhttp.service.ts` I have:

```
public logout() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem(this.tokeyKey);
}

public isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem(this.tokeyKey);

    return token != null;
}
```

In my `account.component.ts` I have:

```
constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthHttpService, private global: GlobalService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptions.push(this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
        this.global.setMetaTitle(data.title);

        this.handleLogout(data.logout == true);
    }));
}

private handleLogout(isLogout: boolean) {
    if (isLogout) {
        this.authService.logout();

        this.router.navigate([""]);
    }
}
```

not sure that it will help, but this is the `route`:

```
{ path: 'account-logout', component: AccountComponent, data: { title: 'Logout - My App', logout: true } },
```

Based on everything that I've read, it's because I'm doing my logout deal in the `ngOnInit` but I'm not sure  about how to handle it otherwise except to either create a `LogoutComponent` or even worse use a `setTimeout` hack, neither of these is desirable... any other options here?

Comment: don't bind to functions `global.isLoggedIn()`

Comment: I tried creating a local `isLoggedIn()` that returned the `global.isLoggedIn()` but that didn't help

Comment: Try using [**async pipe**](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Comment: Can you provide an example? Adding it to the end of `isLoggedIn()` in the view: `*ngIf="global.isLoggedIn() | async"` gave this error: `ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'true' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`

Comment: You don't need to check logged state in account, a route guard can take care of it. The warning comes, as you said, from ngoninit()

Comment: How do you propose me showing and hiding links based on logged in state?

Comment: @SerjSagan, you need to read [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Answer (score 0):

in AppComponent you have to run detection explicitly after the change:

```
constructor(pivate _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
        this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

remember to import it from angular core:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
```